# Form.onFormClosing event handler called in the same thread as Form.Close

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

this is more a concept that I'd like to get correct than a question, so please forgive the vagueness while I try to process this out:

I am developing a Windows tray only application, where I provide a menu option for exiting the app. Since I don't have a close button to close the app, when Exit from the tray menu is called, I handle that event and call Form.Close() explicitly. It seems like Form.onFormClosing() which I override is called on the same thread that I call Form.Close() and Form.onFormClosing() seems to be a synchronous call from Form.Close(). Am I correct in thinking so? If I am, how does this map to when to the Close button is clicked on app?

Comment: Winforms are generally single-threaded, but you can write your own trheads to do some jobs for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. The Livecycle of a form is like this when closing:

- System.Windows.Forms.Form.Closing
- System.Windows.Forms.Form.FormClosing
- System.Windows.Forms.Form.Closed
- System.Windows.Forms.Form.FormClosed
- System.Windows.Forms.Form.Deactivate

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28VS.80%29.aspx

These actions are called one after another once you want to close your form. That's why they are also all on the same thread. The GUI actions are supposed to be run on the main thread (gui thread) anyway.

Comment: So, when the Close button on the app is clicked, am I right in thinking that the default handler calls Form.Close() that then causes a series of calls synchronous calls to Form.onClosing, Form.onFormClosing and so on?